# Proving completely regular is a topological property

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

This question is from Wayne Patty's Topology Page 175.

> Prove that completely regular is a topological property.

I chose C is closed in X and p$\in X-C$, there exists f such f(p)=1  and f(c)=0 for all c$\in C$.

Let X is homeomorphic to Y so there exists a continuous function a : X->Y, such that $a^{-1}$ exists and is continuous.

and let there exists C' closed in Y and p' $\in Y-C'$ . But I am unable to find any function say m such that m(C)=0 and m(p')=1.  But I am not able to find such a function and need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha:Y\rightarrow X$ is an homeomorphism, then it is closed, that is, $\alpha(C)\subseteq X$ is closed for every closed $C\subseteq Y$. Also, since $\alpha$ is 1-1, if $p\in Y-C$, then $\alpha(p)\in X-\alpha(C)$, so using complete regularity of $X$, there is a continuous $i:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $$i(\alpha(p))=1,\qquad i(x)=0\forall x\in\alpha(C)$$so consider $i'=i\circ\alpha:Y\rightarrow[0,1]$, this is a continuous map separating $C$ from $p$

Comment: How to rigoriously prove that if p $\in Y- C$ , then $\alpha(p) \in X -\alpha(C)$? CAn you please tell?

Comment: $\alpha$ is one-to-one (because homeomorphims are bijections) and $p \in Y-C$ implies $p \notin C$, so the image $\alpha (p) \notin \alpha (C)$ (because $\alpha$ is a bijection), which implies $\alpha (p) \in X-\alpha (C)$.